# UIAccessibility.convertToScreenCoordinates() always return a CGRect(0,0,0,0)

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I am trying to increase the hit target of a button within a custom UIView() that is a subview of another parentview.  I use convertToScreenCoordinates() to try and achieve this.  An example is below

```
let rect2 = CGRect(x: 25, y: 21, width: 200, height: 44)
let newRect = UIAccessibility.convertToScreenCoordinates(rect2, in: self)
```

where self is the custom UIView()
debugging, i see that newRect = CGRect(0,0,0,0)

therefore

```
button.accessibilityFrame = newRect // Does not work as intended as VoiceOver frame is now size 0,0 and origin 0,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Turns out that I was setting up the `accessibilityFrame` property before the view was positioned. I fix it by changing this code to the `layoutSubviews` method of my custom view.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let rect2 = CGRect(x: 25, y: 21, width: 200, height: 44)
    let newRect = UIAccessibility.convertToScreenCoordinates(rect2, in: self)
    button.accessibilityFrame = newRect
    }
```